# Connecting HTML buttons to functions of my smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, state

These solidity functions are part of my solidity code which i want to execute them by clickcing on a button on my HTML.One of them stands for accepting bets placeBet() and the other one for sending back the gains to winner gamblers claim().

```
function placeBet(Side _side) public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "Sorry we cannot accept Zero values");
    require(ended == false, "Unfortunately accepting bets is over!!");
    bets[_side] += msg.value;
}

    function claim() public {
    require(ended = true, "Game is not over yet sir!");
    uint gain = gamblerBet + (bets[result.LOSER] * gamblerBet / bets[result.WINNER])
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(gain);
    remainingWithdrawal -= 1;
}
```

Here is my contract instance getting saved into state object.

```
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = PredictionContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
       PredictionContract.abi,
       deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance });
```

As you can see first solidity function accepts a parameter which is defined at the beggining of my script as a struct and second function does not need any parameter.
I have used truffle react box for user interface.Inside of App.js file after saving the contract instance into the state object i wanted to access its functions as below but it didn't work.
Here are a button refers to claim() function and a button for placeBet() in my render section.

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.claim}>CLAIM YOUR REWARD :)</button>
<input type="button" onClick={this.submitBetA} value="PLACE BET"/>
```

And finally here are my Javascript functions to connect buttons to their intended smart contract function but it does not work as well.

```
submitBetA = () => {
this.state.contract.methods.placeBet("0").send({from: this.state.accounts[0], value: this.state.amountA})}
claim = () => {
this.state.contract.methods.claim().send({from: this.state.accounts[0]})}
```

Values for submitBetA is taken from my state object.
Could anyone tell me where is my problem cause the buttons doesn't work properly.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work properly" what exactly do you mean? transaction fails, it isn't generated, some other error. Also what is `Side`? You said it is an struct but you send "0" as parameter, is the "0" the correct value? What solidity version are you using?

Comment: I use "1" and "0" to interact with my function that needs parameter

Comment: doesn't work properly means By clicking the related button to the function nothing really happens

Comment: Try adding console.log around the function to determine if the button work. Did you check if anything appears on the browser console?